# Assertions about a square, diagonalizable matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

How many of the following assertions are true for a $n \times n$ diagonalizable matrix $X$?

- There is an invertible matrix $Q$ such that $Q$$X$$Q$<sup>-1</sup>

> I think this assertion is true because if $X$ is diagonalizable, then there exists an inverttible matrix P such that $P$<sup>-1</sup>$X$$P$ is a diagonal matrix. 
>   Let $Q$=$P$<sup>-1</sup> then we have that $Q$$X$$Q$<sup>-1</sup> is a diagonal matrix.

- $X$ has n linearly independent eigenvectors

> This assertion is true because a diagonalizable matrix has $n$ linearly independent vectors.

- $X$ is invertible

> I don't think this one is true because if $X$ has $0$ as an eigenvalue, $D$=$P$<sup>-1</sup>$X$$P$ will not be invertible and since $X$ and $D$ are similar, X will not be invertible.

This is from a past paper question for Linear Algebra, it says that the answer is 2 of the assertions are true but it does not say which of them are true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct!

- Assuming you meant ... "is diagonal", then yes, since $\mathbf P$
  is invertible $\mathbf Q = \mathbf P^{-1}$ works.
- Again, this is true. If you like, you can justify it further by writing
  $\mathbf X = \mathbf P \mathbf D \mathbf P^{-1}$ for some diagonal matrix
  $\mathbf D$, and then each column of $\mathbf P$ must be an eigenvector of
  $\mathbf X$, but since $\mathbf P$ is invertible, its columns must be linearly
  independent.
- Once again, you're correct. When the answer to a question like this is
  negative, it's often a good idea to provide an explicit counterexample if you
  can find one. This can be helpful to avoid certain kinds of flawed reasoning.
  In this case, you could use
  \begin{equation*}
     \mathbf I^{-1}
     \begin{pmatrix}
      0 & 0 \\
      0 & 0
     \end{pmatrix}
     \mathbf I
     = \begin{pmatrix}
      0 & 0 \\
      0 & 0
     \end{pmatrix}
    \end{equation*}
  which is clearly not invertible.